# Can you use a digital camera CCD to make an image without a lens?

Tags: optics, microscopy

What would you be able to see if you took off the lens of a digital camera and placed a drop of pond water containing microbes/amoebas directly on the sensor? Would you be able to see an image? The resolution of a cell phone camera these days is about a micrometer so I'd think you'd be able to see something.

Comment: see https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Class/refrn/u14l5c.cfm "plane mirror" paragraph.

Comment: If the illumination is coherent then a holographic arrangement can be used used to form a lensless image.